# How to import keys in intern 4?

Tags: intern

I'm trying to press tab key in one of my  test using [intern framework](https://theintern.io) but i'm unable to do so . I have tried using 
`var keys = require("keys"); , 
import * as keys from keys and 
var keys = require("leadfoot/keys");` 
but non of these worked i am getting   `Cannot find module` error can someone please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the keys module as follows:

`const keys = require('@theintern/leadfoot/keys').default;`

Comment: Interesting. Are you using babel?

Comment: It has been a while since I used this statement for any reason so my memory is a bit hazy. It was related to something I was trying out in my workplace which, in the end, we didn't go ahead with and so the code is long gone. I'll have to retry this again - Babel was used when we were building our project, though!

Comment: Just retried it in my workspace (as we are still using InternJS) and it worked perfectly. So have updated my above answer!